# No output of type SPLIT_LIST after update gradle to 3.0.0-alpha5

Tags: gradle

After update gradle to 3.0.0-alpha5 my project can't sync gradle.

I received this message:

`Gradle sync failed: No output of type: SPLIT_LIST`

and in `idea.log` something about my `release` variant:

`Variant 'release' has no output with type 'SPLIT_LIST'`

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a solution to this?

Comment: @Hades I doesn't found it so far. Ticket is created here:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63217768 and it looks like they have own ticket for this and they know this problem. So probably we just need to wait for fix

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is with `shrinkResources` config. Removing it is temporary solution for now. Unfortunately I didn't find any info about deprecation of that so I think it's a bug.

Comment: Thank you so much. This answer saved me days of hit and trial

Comment: They probably fix this: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65829618 but it can be a different problem. Need to try Android Studio 3.0 RC1 ;)